# How to make a age calculation program where the response time will also be counted

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, time, printing

So guys, I got this tricky question. I'm trying to make a program using GUI interface that counts how long took the user to write down the input. I got more or less the idea of what I need but sadly I lack the knowledge on how to make it. An interface that counts seconds and at the end shows how many seconds took you to answer the questions. I already made the GUI questions input/output. if anyone knows how to make a timer  with GUI interface I would appreciate it.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @NomadMaker Improve my knowledge in java , i learn a lot by doing things i didn't knew how to make.  In my oppinion it's the best way to truly learn something.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks Avid system.currenttimemills() is a good option but what  i need is a code that counts seconds in a GUI interface, i'm already making a thread so the counting happens at the same time when the questions start dropping. To at the end print how long took to answer.

Comment: @Butcherbill - Did you execute the code in my answer? It also prints the elapsed time in seconds. If you need anything else, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61902590/edit) your question and clarify what else you need.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash i did and showed in the console not in a GUI interface .

Comment: @Butcherbill - I've updated the answer to display the message in GUI as well. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @Butcherbill - Any update?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) which returns the current time in milliseconds e.g.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Record time before input
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int nasc = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "when were u born?"));
        int act = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "which year are you in?"));
        int cal = act - nasc;
        System.out.println("You are " + cal + "years old");

        // Current time - start time = elapsed milliseconds
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 + " sec");

        // Display the message in GUI
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Total elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 + " sec");
    }
}
```